# retrieve data to textboxt using LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, visual-studio-2013

hi all i want to ask about retrieve data to textbox using LINQ to SQL c#
i'm using visual studio 2013 Ultimate Edition

i have a *.dbml file and some textboxt..

this is the code :

```
DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        var query = from c in db.Library
                    select c.Book;
```

and i want to retrieve data to :

```
**textboxt**<hr>
title.text;<br>
name.text;<br>
bookcode.text;<hr>
```

NB : using C# (LINQ to SQL) winform Visual Studio 2013

Comment: so your `City` contains property `Title`, `Name`, and `BookCode`? Even if that's true, `query` return all cities available in `db`. How you want to display all of them in 3 textboxes?

Comment: i'm sorry i forget to edit the code...
i'm just copy paste from the sample..

Comment: ok, I assume that answer to the 1st question is *true*, after changing `City` to `Book`. Then how about the second? or you want to get only one book from database instead of all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var query = from c in db.Library
                    select c.Book;

Above code will return multiple record of books.
So  you have to loop over "query"

for eg

foreach (var q in query)

```
        {
            Response.Write(q.ToString()); // "q" will have your database record
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code that you have posted, it'll return you a result set of all the books present in the Library. So, first you need to select a particular book based on some condition in your query. Or, you can also select one book by FirstOrDefault()(does not make sense to just do this, just saying).

After you get one book, you can display the values in textboxes like so

```
txtTitle.Text = query.Title;
txtName.Text = query.Name; //and so on
```

If you want to display all the books values then you need to iterate through the result set and display them accordingly.

Let me know if you further help on this.